# Multiple variables to multiply based on condition gives error

Tags: excel, vba

i have searched all of this site for a solution but was unable to find one that suited my needs, I am an expert user of excel, but started to learn VBA, and got stuck on this error for some days now.
i need to multiply a value by a currency, and as I have a lot of currencies I thought that this was the proper way to do it (please see code below) but I got this error that I cant solve, can anyone help me to with this, please?
thanks in advance.

```
Sub Update_Janeiro()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim Cambio_Jan As Currency

If Cells(i, 251) = EUR Then
        Cambio_Jan = 1
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = USD Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.801228726
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = GBP Then
        Cambio_Jan = 1.1414211803
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = CNY Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.1271895307
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = NAIRAS Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0016670478
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = AUD Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.6431760061
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = GHS Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = CZK Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0397256232
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = KES Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0078621931
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = ZAR Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0676563785
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = ZMK Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0000829218
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = TZS Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0003555818
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = SGD Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.6117066233
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = UGX Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.000221247
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = RON Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.2149924803
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = RUB Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0141866904
    Else: Cambio_Jan = 0

End If

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "IA").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 3 To lngLastRow
        Cells(i, 261).Value = Cells(i, 255) + Cells(i, 256)
        Cells(i, 262).Value = Cells(i, 259) * Cambio_Jan
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

UPDATED CODE

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Janeiro()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim Cambio_Jan As Double
Dim i As Integer
i = i

If Cells(i, 251) = "EUR" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 1
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "USD" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.801228726
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "GBP" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 1.1414211803
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "CNY" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.1271895307
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "NAIRAS" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0016670478
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "AUD" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.6431760061
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "GHS" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "CZK" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0397256232
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "KES" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0078621931
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "ZAR" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0676563785
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "ZMK" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0000829218
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "TZS" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0003555818
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "SGD" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.6117066233
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "UGX" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.000221247
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "RON" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.2149924803
    ElseIf Cells(i, 251) = "RUB" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 0.0141866904
    Else: Cambio_Jan = 0

End If

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "IA").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 3 To lngLastRow
        Cells(i, 261).Value = Cells(i, 255) + Cells(i, 256)
        Cells(i, 262).Value = Cells(i, 259) * Cambio_Jan
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: _I got this error that I cant solve_  - what's the error and which line does it occur on?

Comment: What's the value of `i` at the start of the code?  When you hit the `If Cells(i, 251) = EUR Then` line it looks like `i` will equal `0`.  If you've got `Option Explicit` at the top of your code you should get _Variable not defined_ error.

Comment: the error is run-time error 1004 it occurs after this code: Sub Update_Janeiro()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim Cambio_Jan As Currency

If Cells(i, 251) = "EUR" Then
        Cambio_Jan = 1

Comment: `i = i` doesn't make sense `i` needs to be set to a value (a number!) or you need to move all `i` it into your `For i` loop.

Comment: i changed i to 3 since i want the changes to occur in column 259 based on the currenci code in cell 251  for every row from the 3rd onwards until the last filled row, but now the code doesn't give an error, it simply doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that you can use `Select Case`
2. If you use `Cells(i, 251) = EUR` the `EUR` is a variable not a string.
   You need to use quotes `Cells(i, 251) = "EUR"`
3. Your `i` is not defined and there is no row `0`. Define `i` or use a loop with `i`.

   ```
   i = 1 'you must define i

   Select Case Cells(i, 251)
       Case "EUR":    Cambio_Jan = 1
       Case "USD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.801228726
       Case "GBP":    Cambio_Jan = 1.1414211803
       Case "CNY":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1271895307
       Case "NAIRAS": Cambio_Jan = 0.0016670478
       Case "AUD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.6431760061
       Case "GHS":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
       Case "CZK":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
       Case "KES":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0078621931
       Case "ZAR":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0676563785
       Case "ZMK":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0000829218
       Case "TZS":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0003555818
       Case "SGD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.6117066233
       Case "UGX":    Cambio_Jan = 0.000221247
       Case "RON":    Cambio_Jan = 0.2149924803
       Case "RUB":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0141866904
       Case Else:     Cambio_Jan = 0
   End Select
   ```

   Anyway I cannot recommend storing these values in the code. Make them available in an extra worksheet, so you can easily update them.
4. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly.
5. You used the type `Currency` (see [Currency Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type))

   > *Currency variables are stored as 64-bit (8-byte) numbers in an integer format, scaled by 10,000 to give a fixed-point number with 15 digits to the left of the decimal point and 4 digits to the right.*

   But you use more than 4 digits. Switch to type `Double`.

---

So you end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_Janeiro()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "IA").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Cambio_Jan As Double

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long 'must be long!
    For i = 3 To lngLastRow
        Select Case Cells(i, 251)
            Case "EUR":    Cambio_Jan = 1
            Case "USD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.801228726
            Case "GBP":    Cambio_Jan = 1.1414211803
            Case "CNY":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1271895307
            Case "NAIRAS": Cambio_Jan = 0.0016670478
            Case "AUD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.6431760061
            Case "GHS":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
            Case "CZK":    Cambio_Jan = 0.1778598686
            Case "KES":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0078621931
            Case "ZAR":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0676563785
            Case "ZMK":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0000829218
            Case "TZS":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0003555818
            Case "SGD":    Cambio_Jan = 0.6117066233
            Case "UGX":    Cambio_Jan = 0.000221247
            Case "RON":    Cambio_Jan = 0.2149924803
            Case "RUB":    Cambio_Jan = 0.0141866904
            Case Else:     Cambio_Jan = 0
        End Select

        Cells(i, 261).Value = Cells(i, 255) + Cells(i, 256)
        Cells(i, 262).Value = Cells(i, 259) * Cambio_Jan
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: made all the changes including the 'dim i as integer', but it gives the same error at the same locations of the code. any ideas?

Comment: Add the updated code into your original question below the current code, so we can see the differences.

Comment: See my edit. This could work. Your `i` must be within the `For i` loop. Otherwise it doesn't count the `i` and it is `0`.

Comment: Thanks alot PEH, this worked :) you are a life saver

Comment: @P.Costa I still recommend writing all the cambio values into a worksheet instead of having them in the code. Much easier to update then.